# ffmpeg decode video to YUV and damaged pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I use [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/decode_video_8c-example.html) example to decode a mpeg1 [video](https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mpeg/sample_640x360.mpeg)

when decode starts

log (every 3 to 10 frames) :

```
[mpeg1video @ 0x5626caf74e40] ac-tex damaged at 39 15
[mpeg1video @ 0x5626caf74e40] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg1video @ 0x5626caf74e40] concealing 405 DC, 405 AC, 405 MV errors in P frame
```

and the result is :

[image]

I tried make rgb from YUV using opencv but the rgb results is same

```
    cv::Size actual_size(frame->width, frame->height);
    cv::Size half_size(frame->width/2, frame->height/2);
    cv::Mat y(actual_size, CV_8UC1, frame->data[0]);
    cv::Mat u(half_size, CV_8UC1, frame->data[1]);
    cv::Mat v(half_size, CV_8UC1, frame->data[2]);

    cv::Mat u_resized, v_resized;
    cv::resize(u, u_resized, actual_size, 0, 0, cv::INTER_NEAREST); //repeat u values 4 times
    cv::resize(v, v_resized, actual_size, 0, 0, cv::INTER_NEAREST); //repeat v values 4 times

    cv::Mat yuv; 
    std::vector<cv::Mat> yuv_channels = { y, u_resized, v_resized };
    cv::merge(yuv_channels, yuv);

    cv::Mat bgr;
    cv::cvtColor(yuv, bgr, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR);
    
    cv::imshow("x",bgr);
    cv::waitKey(1000/25);
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: the question is why this happen (bad pixels) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved by using [mpeg2 video](https://filesamples.com/samples/video/m2v/sample_640x360.m2v) and AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO

```
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
```